# React Native Expo components overlapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, shoutem

I just started with React Native, and I made my first two components,namely an `AppBar` and a `ProductCard`. I stacked them in `App.js` just like in React, but the components are overlapping on each other.. I tried using `flexDirection: 'column'` but no luck still.. Is there any `position` I can change inorder to get these in a stack? Also, I'm using shoutem UI..

Code for AppBar.js and ProductCard.js :

```
render() {
    return (
      <NavigationBar
        centerComponent={<Title>BHAAW</Title>}
        style={{
          container: {
            backgroundColor: "#42f445"
          }}}
      />
    )}


       render()
        return(
         <Card>
          <View styleName="content">
            <View styleName="horizontal v-center space-between">
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
```

App.js:

```
return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight}}>
        <AppBar />
        <ProductCard />
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: ```styleName``` in React Native?

Comment: Its a shoutem prop I believe.

Comment: can you provide a working snack using https://snack.expo.io/ ?